# Keep a thread running while on breakpoint in another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible in VS2012 to keep a distinct thread (or a special part of it) running, while breaking and single stepping the programm?

The reason why I ask is because I have a thread communicating with a connected hardware device, which may run into timeouts, if it doesn't get commands from my thread. An option would be to do the communication in another process, but I don't want to do this, because it's only a problem with debugging.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with C# and WPF.

Comment: I was looking for this too. For similar reason. I guess the answer is no - you cannot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use tracepoints instead of breakpoint. Tracepoint will not stop execution, instead you can specify the VS debugger to log the value of the watch objects which will log it to Output Window of Visual Studio.

> Tracepoints are another way to use breakpoints. A tracepoint is a
>   breakpoint that prints a message to the Output window. A tracepoint
>   can act like a temporary trace statement in the programming language.
>
> To print a message at an existing breakpoint, open the context menu
>   for the breakpoint and choose When Hit.
>
> You specify the message to print in the When Breakpoint Is Hit dialog
>   box

Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx)